# Allow markup inside drupal 8 Link function

Tags: 8, theming

I always try to use the core functions for linking in drupal, but I'm not able to add html markup like `<a href="..."><span>Link text</span></a>`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the Markup class:

```
use Drupal\Core\Link;
use Drupal\Core\Url;
use Drupal\Core\Render\Markup;

$url = Url::fromUri('http://www.example.com');     
$linkText = 'My link <br> containing tags';
$linkMarkup = Markup::create($linkText);
$link = Link::fromTextAndUrl($linkMarkup, $url);
$link = $link->toRenderable();
```

Answer (score 6):

If you build a render array for the link you can simply place the html markup in `#markup`:

```
$build['my_link'] = [
  '#type' => 'link',
  '#title' => [
    '#markup' => 'My link <br> containing tags',
  ],
  '#url' => Url::fromUri('http://www.example.com'),
];
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is a Drupal field, I find it easier and cleaner to do it in `hook_preprocess_field`:

```
  if ($variables['field_name'] == 'field_myfield') {
    foreach ($variables['items'] as $key => $item) {
      $variables['items'][$key]['content']['#options']['attributes']['class'][] = 'hl__button';
      $variables['items'][$key]['content']['#options']['attributes']['title'] = t('Visit link for "@title"', ['@title' => $item['content']['#title']]);

      $variables['items'][$key]['content']['#title'] = new FormattableMarkup('<span class="hl__button__text">@title</span>', [
        '@title' => $item['content']['#title'],
      ]);
    }
  }
```

That way you can affect other attributes or add more.